# What is the syntax error in this code? Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ('\t -m, --method\t\tHTTP Method to use \'get\' or \'post\'  or \'random\'\t\t(default: get)')
```

Syntax error : Invalid syntax

[image]

```
    print (GOLDENEYE_BANNER)
print 
print (' USAGE: ./goldeneye.py <url> [OPTIONS]')
print
print (' OPTIONS:')
print ('\t Flag\t\t\tDescription\t\t\t\t\t\tDefault')
print ('\t -u, --useragents\tFile with user-agents to use\t\t\t\t(default: randomly generated)')
print ('\t -w, --workers\t\tNumber of concurrent workers\t\t\t\t(default: {0})'.format(DEFAULT_WORKERS))

print ('\t -s, --sockets\t\tNumber of concurrent sockets\t\t\t\t(default: {0})'.format(DEFAULT_SOCKETS)
print ('\t -m, --method\t\tHTTP Method to use \'get\' or \'post\'  or \'random\'\t\t(default: get)')
print ('\t -d, --debug\t\tEnable Debug Mode [more verbose output]\t\t\t(default: False)')
print ('\t -h, --help\t\tShows this help')
```

Comment: Works fine in Python 3.4.3. on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @NZD see the picture .. i work on windows

Comment: The fault is then very likely in the previous line. To check that, comment out the line with 'print', it should then still give you the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Please show the entire file

Comment: i added, see the picture

Comment: are you sure py is linked to python3 instead of python2?

Comment: You have a missing closing parenthesis on the preceding line.

Comment: See how the first `format` call ends with two parentheses? The next line needs to do the same. Can't have unmatched parentheses or things break. Next time you get a syntax error, proofread your code more carefully.

Comment: I only had python 3 on my computer, and if i use python instead of py it shows me the error "python is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question next time.

Comment: thank you all it works now as TigerhawkT3 said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on line 553. You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Line 553 should be:

```
print('\t -s, --sockets\t\tNumber of concurrent sockets\t\t\t\t(default: {0})'.format(DEFAULT_SOCKETS))
```

Comment: yes it works fine now